# Objective-C の Delegateとは？

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegate

今までなんとなく Objective-C の Delegate を使っていましたが、もっと理解を深めたいと考えています。 現在は「UITableView を使いたいから Delegate しないと」程度の認識です。

- Delegate の正確な意味合い
- 設計上の位置付け

はどういったものなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

Objective-Cの「デリゲート(delegate)」は、プログラミング言語Objective-Cが提供する特定機能をさすのではなく、アプリケーション実装における[デザインパターン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3_%28%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%29)の一種です。（一例として、Objective-Cとは異なり、C#ではdelegateという言語"機能"が存在します。）

Objective-Cのデリゲートは単なるパターン（≒設計上の決まり事）ですから、ソフトウェア設計者間で共通認識を持つためにも、コーディングを行う上では一定のルール付けが必要とされます。以下、Apple公式ドキュメント「[Objective-Cプログラミングの概念](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CocoaEncyclopedia.pdf)」からの抜粋です。（読みやすさのため本質でない部分は削りました）

22ページ:

> デリゲート(delegate, 委譲)とは、あるオブジェクトがプログラム中でイベントに遭遇したとき、それに代わって、または連携して処理するオブジェクトのことです。
>   [...]
>   デリゲートの仕組み
>   デリゲートの設計は単純です。委譲する側のクラス（デリゲートクラス）には、一般にdelegateという名前の、アウトレットまたはプロパティがあります。[...]

24ページ:

> デリゲートメッセージの形式
>   デリゲートメソッドの名前のつけ方には規約があります。[...]

28ページ:

> カスタムクラスにデリゲートを実装する手順は次の通りです。
>   * クラスのヘッダファイルに、デリゲートのアクセサメソッドを宣言する。[...]
>   * アクセサメソッドを実装する。[...]
>   * デリゲートに対するプロトコルを宣言する。[...]

Answer (score 1):

kmugitaniさんがおっしゃられているように、まずは公式のドキュメントを読んでみると良いと思います（ページ数もそんなにないですし）。  
読んでみてなんとなく分かったら、自分でDelegateを持ったクラスを作成するとより理解が深まると思います。

だいぶ端折っていますが、Objective-Cならこんな感じです。
**MyView.h**

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
// プロセス完了時に実行される
-(void)processCompletion
@end
```

**MyView.m**

```
-(void)completion
{
    // MyViewで必要な処理を実行する

    // デリゲートメソッドを呼ぶ
    [_delegate processCompletion];
}
```

あと、これは参考になるか分かりませんが、少しだけ他の言語を触ってみると気づきがあるかもしれません。
自分の場合はAndroidのEventListenerを触った時に少し分かった気がしました。

Answer (score 1):

オブジェクト指向及び delegate については以下の資料の
「最強オブジェクト指向言語 JavaScript 再入門！」
http://www.slideshare.net/yuka2py/javascript-23768378
下記のスライドのあたりが個人的にはいちばん参考になりました。
[image: new]
[image: delegate]

Answer (score 0):

[Objective-Cプログラミングの概念 Apple 日本語版](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CocoaEncyclopedia.pdf)　のページ22からを、まずは読んでみれば、どうでしょうか。