# iOSでのカスタムダイアログの表示

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, dialog

ボタンが押されるとカスタムダイアログを表示するといったプログラムを組んでいるのですが、
ルートの`ViewController`に`Main.Storyboard`にあるダイアログ用の`ViewController`を表示させるにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？色々と調べていても実装例が少なく、下記のサイトを参考にしているのですがうまくいきません。（特に`objc_setAssociatedObject`というところで躓いてしまってます。。。）
https://codeiq.jp/magazine/2014/05/9493/

どなたかカスタムダイアログの表示のさせ方が分かる方がいればご教授いただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: あなたのiOS開発の習熟度によって、回答の内容が変わります。スタンダードなインターフェイスである、モーダルやポップオーバーの表示は、マスターしている。それとは異なるインターフェイスを使わなければいけない必然性が生じて、「別ウインドウ」の表示をプログラムしなければいけない。あなたの習熟度がそういうレベルなのか、はたまたモーダル表示のしかたもわかってないのか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。モーダルやポップオーバーの表示は大丈夫ですが、ダイアログとしてViewControllerの内容を表示させたいです。やりたいことを流れで説明しますと、Storyboardでダイアログ用のViewControllerにボタンやイメージを配置して、それをボタンが押されるとルートのViewController上にダイアログとして表示するといった具合です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

参考ページでは`UIWindow`を使用しているようなので、
おそらくやりたい事とは異なると思いますが、参考程度になれば幸いです。
※すみません、参考先はあまり読んでいません。

単純に`Storyboard`上の`ViewController`を表示させるだけなら下記のようなコードで可能です。

```
- (IBAction)touchUp:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    CustomDialogViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CustomDialogViewController class])];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ただ、これだと背景が真っ黒になってしまいますので、
別案として`UIViewController`ではなく`UIView`を使用する方法もあります。

```
- (IBAction)touchUpAdd:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CustomDialogView* view = [CustomDialogView loadFromNib];
    view.delegate = self;
    view.frame = self.view.frame;
    view.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

こちらの方法だと背景に呼び出し元の`ViewController`を残すことが可能ですが、
`Storyboard`ではなく`xib`を用意する必要があります（`xib`を作るのが嫌であれば全部コードで書くことも可能です）。

・UIViewControllerの場合
[image: UIViewController]

・UIViewの場合
[image: UIView]

----- 追記 -----
`loadFromNib`は下記のような実装です。
`xib`から読み込む場合のお決まりのような感じ（細部が若干異なる場合はあります）なので、
`UIView`のカテゴリで用意しておくと、いちいち書かなくて良いので楽です。

```
+(id)loadFromNib
{
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                          owner:nil
                                        options:nil]
            firstObject];
}
```

`view.delegate`はとりあえず消してしまっても動きに問題はありません。  
Objective-CのDelegateに関しては下記の質問が参考になると思います。
[Objective-C の Delegateとは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4930)

`xib`の作成方法はご認識の通りで問題ありません。
作成後に`xib`のアイデンティティインスペクタでCustom Classを紐付けるのを忘れないように気をつけて下さい。

念のための補足事項として、ダイアログ（CustomView）を閉じる際は、
`removeFromSuperview`を使用します。
※見えなくするだけなら`alpha`や`hidden`でも大丈夫だと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。動作や使い方を解説してくださり、とてもありがたいです。呼び出し元の背景はそのままにしておきたいので、2番目のxibを使う方法で行こうと考えているのですが、上記のコードのloadFromNibとview.delegateでエラーが出てしまっています。分からないことだらけで申し訳ないのですが、何か他に設定することがあるのでしょうか？ちなみにxibファイルはXcodeの「File」→「New」→「File」→「User Interface/View」で作り、再びStoryboardで作ったようにUIを配置していけばよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu 追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事にxibファイルのレイアウトを画面に表示させることができました！本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @kojianu お役に立てたようで何よりです。一点記載が漏れてしまったのですが、上記の表示方法でダイアログを閉じる際に`alpha`や`hidden`でやると複数回ダイアログを開いた際に`View`がどんどん積み重なってしまうので気をつけて下さい。

Comment: 了解いたしました。本当に助かります。ご指摘の点気をつけます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

つまづいているところの説明

```
objc_setAssociatedObject
```

> // ウィンドウのオーナーとしてアプリ自身に括りつけとく
>       objc_setAssociatedObject([UIApplication sharedApplication], &kAssocKey_Window, window, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

上記の意味はシングルトンのインスタンス`[UIApplication sharedApplication]`に`&kAssocKey_Window`というキー名で`window`というオブジェクトデータを`nonatomic,retain`の属性で保持する。という内容です。

`window`を取り出したい時には下記のようにします。(取り出したwinは多分UIWindowクラス型)

```
id win = objc_getAssociatedObject([UIApplication sharedApplication],&kAssocKey_Window);
```

上記は特殊なデータ保持の方法で、通常であれば各クラスで定義したプロパティに保持するようなデータをインスタンスに対して直接保持させることができます。
この機能を使えば標準のフレームワーク内の各クラス(UIApplication,NSStringなどなんでも良い)の**インスタンス**に直接**オブジェクトデータを保持できます**。

利用シーンとして、カテゴリなどでは通常はインスタンス変数を追加できないですが、この機能を使えば擬似的にプロパティを追加することができます。

下記をインポートすると使えます。

```
objc/runtime.h
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。これはオブジェクトを保持するという意味だったのですね。。。インスタンスに直接オブジェクトデータを保持できるなんてビックリしました。知識が広がりました。誠にありがとうございます。