# xibで作ったカスタムダイアログとイベントハンドラを紐付ける

Tags: objective-c, xib

[iOSでのカスタムダイアログの表示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7007/ios%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA)

上記のベストアンサーの方法でダイアログを表示させることはできたのですが、作成した`xib`のボタンをコードと紐付けて実行し、ボタンをタップするとアプリが動かなくなってしまいました。エラーは何も出ていません。この場合何が原因となっているのでしょうか？すみません、どなたか分かる方がいればご教授いただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

postDialog.h

```
@interface PostDialog : UIView

+(id)loadFromNib;

- (IBAction)post:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

postDialog.m

```
@interface PostDialog ()

@end

@implementation PostDialog

+(id)loadFromNib {
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
}

- (IBAction)post:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"post");
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}

@end
```

------追記------

コンソールにログを出力しました。

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x3b6f, 0x0000000198c23bdc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 28, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
    frame #0: 0x0000000198c23bdc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 28
    frame #1: 0x000000018cca9418 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #2: 0x000000018cc9252c UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
    frame #3: 0x000000018cca8db4 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
    frame #4: 0x000000018cca8a40 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
    frame #5: 0x000000018cca1f94 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
    frame #6: 0x000000018cc7568c UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
    frame #7: 0x000000018cf1460c UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992
    frame #8: 0x000000018cc73bf4 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
    frame #9: 0x000000018847e9ec CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #10: 0x000000018847dc90 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
    frame #11: 0x000000018847bd40 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 712
    frame #12: 0x00000001883a90a4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #13: 0x00000001915435a4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #14: 0x000000018ccdaaa4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #15: 0x0000000100032db0 PostDialog`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdd3a60) + 116 at main.m:14
    frame #16: 0x000000019927ea08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: **アプリが動かなくなった**という部分が掴みかねているのですが、xibの`User Interaction Enabled`のチェックが外れていたりしませんか（ボタンにチェックが入っていても親のビューが外れていたら動かないです）？（もし、それまで動いていたものがフリーズするのであれば全然別問題です）。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。xibと親ViewのUser Interaction Enabledのチャックは外れていませんでした。xibのボタンを押すまでアプリは動いており、xibのボタンを押すとエラーもなくアプリが動かなくなります。。。

Comment: なるほど。Xcodeのコンソールにログも出ませんか？

Comment: すみません、コンソールにログは出ないのですが、maniの「return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));」に緑線で「Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x01)」というメッセージが出ています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xib`ファイルを選択した状態で、Xcodeの**コネクションインスペクタ**を選択してみてください（一番右のインスペクタです）。

一度作成したが名前を変えた（あるいは削除した）等で存在しなくなった
`IBAction`が紐付いていないでしょうか？

----- 追記 -----
**Sent Events**というのがありませんか？
添付画像の例だと Closeボタンに IBActionが2つ紐付いていますが、.m に`touchtouch`というメソッドが実装されていません（これでボタンを押下すると main で `Thread1:signal SIGABRT`になります）。

ちなみに

> maniの「return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
>   NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));」に緑線で「Thread 1:
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x01)」というメッセージが出ています。

これはアプリがクラッシュして止まっている状態なので、エラーは出ていますね。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 確認したところ、「Outlet Collections」、「Referencing Outlets」、「Referencing Outlet Collections」の三つともどこにも紐付いていませんでした。現在は白い空白の丸が表示されています。

Comment: @kojianu 本文を追加しました。あと、次にmainで止まったらXcodeのコンソールに「bt」と入力してEnterを押してみてください（多少情報が得られるかもしれません）。

Comment: ログを追記いたしました。
Sent Eventを探したのですが、見つかりませんでした。。。.mには、.hに紐付けした際の「post」と「cancel」メソッドを実装してあります。

Comment: @kojianu ありがとうございます。**Sent Events**はUIButtonを選択すると見つかると思います。[UIKit - UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent: crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241484) 、[EXC_BAD_ACCESS with IBACTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070204)  あたりを見ると、ターゲットが解放済みなのが原因だと思うのですが、ログを出すだけの処理で発生するのかが疑問です。

Comment: Sent Eventsを見つけました。確認したところ、「Touch Up inside - File's Owner post: 」となっており、横の丸が黒丸になっていました。
xibとコードの紐付け以外が原因の可能性は低いでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu 返信遅くなりました。「Touch Up inside - File's Owner post: 」ここが**File's Owner**になっているのが問題だと思います。普通はカスタムビューと紐付いています（上記の画像をご参照ください）。File's Ownerは`NSObject`のままにして、IBActionを紐付ける際はAssistant Editorを使って.m or .h にActionを設定してみてください（今紐付いている`Touch Up inside - File's Owner post:`を消すのも忘れないでください。）。

Comment: すみません、Assistant Editorを使って.hファイルとボタンを紐付けようとすると、必ず「object」の欄が「File's Owner」になってしまいます。また、「File's OwnerはNSObjectのまま」とはどういうことを行えばそうなるのでしょうか？すみません、ゴールまであと一歩のところと感じており、あと少しお助けいただきたいです。

Comment: すみません、Custom Classの欄を設定したところ、うまくいきそうです！
もう少しトライしてみます！

Comment: ありがとうございます！ボタンが押されたことを検知することができました！本当にありがとうございました！親身なご指導、本当に感謝しております。

Answer (score 1):

エラーの時に少しでもログを多く出す方法を記載します。
AppDelegate.mに下記のメソッドを追加してください。

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
}
```

次にAppDelegate.mの下記メソッド内に一行コードを追加してください。

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler); // <-これを追加
    // その他色々な処理
}
```

これでエラー時にログが**出る場合があります。**
ログが出た場合は追記して頂くと原因究明のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示の方法でログを出そうとすると今回の場合出なかったのですが、今後の役に立つテクニックなのでとてもありがたいです。ありがとうございます。